# Is it possible to save additional fields in Google Smart lock api?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-smartlockpasswords

I am trying to save the following fields: email, password and country to Google smart lock. I am in a case where a user can have the same email and password on different countries - so the country field is important to identify the user. Does anyone know how to add this extra field?

Comment: So each country has it own backend account system? And they all use the same client app? Which app is it?

Comment: Well sort of, they all use the same backend but the accounts from one country has some differences with one from another country. It is an app for a food delivery company called hellofresh. It is highly unlikely that someone from UK would have an account from US for example - but the country field is important to identify the user.

Comment: Hmmm, ya unfortunately, there are no extra fields per se to save data such as user country (try to keep the API surface simple, but will keep it in mind if I hear similar use cases). One (slightly hacky) trick would be to append the country info to display name field and parse it out when the info is retrieved. Note that this will show in the UI to user though. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/Credential.Builder.html#setName(java.lang.String)

Comment: @StevenSoneff Do you know if there is any update in the SDK to resolve this issue?

Comment: Sorry, no plans at the moment. Did you try just appending country info to the display name and parse that out for whatever purposes you have?

Comment: We did not want to do that way because the appended information would be shown in the dialog(if there is multiple account, right?)

Comment: That's correct, it would show in the UI, but unfortunately, there is no general way to store meta-data at the moment.